# Consulta SQL no muestra tabla en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una consulta en sql que en el phpmyadmin muestra lo que requiero, pero al pasarla al fichero php no muestra nada, y si le quito el group by solo me muestra un una fila, alguna sugerencia!! (FUNCIONA EN MYSQL PERO EN PHP NO)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['tag'])){
  try{
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbregistroscajero;charset=UTF8','root','');

    $sql = "SELECT empleados.noEmpleado, empleados.nombre, fechaHoraS, count(registro) as total from registro inner join empleados on registro.empleado = empleados.noEmpleado where date_format(fechaHoraS, '%Y-%m-%d') >='2016-02-16' order by fechaHoraS desc limit 0,300";

    $result = $conn->prepare($sql)or die($sql);

    if(!$result->execute()) return false;

    if($result->rowCount() > 0){
      $json=array();

      while($row=$result->fetch()){
        $json[]=array(
          'Dato1' => $row['noEmpleado'],
          'Dato2' => $row['nombre'],
          'Dato3' => $row['fechaHoraS'],
          'Dato4' => $row['nombre'],
          'Dato5' => $row['total']
        );
      }
      $json['success'] = true;
      echo json_encode($json);
    }

  }catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'Error: ' .$e->getMessage();
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: da algún error? podrías poner el código que ejecutas en PHP para enviar la consulta?

Comment: no, cero error solo que solo manda una fila, en realidad es la unica tabla que me esta dando problema, ya que esta tiene como objetivo mostrar un historial.

Comment: lo siento mucho por el orden de el codigo, pero aun no se como ordenarlo en stackover... @ArielOctavioD'Alfeo

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta en vez de dejar el código en los comentarios

Comment: Lo siento @CarlosMuñoz, es la primera vez que realizo una pregunta en la pagina!

Comment: No te preocupes, ya aprendiste :)

Comment: PERO BUENO, REGRESANDO AL TEMA COMO LO REPITO, EL DETALLE ESTA SOMALENTE EN LA CONSULTA SQL!

Comment: Si la consulta funciona bien cuando la ejecutas en Mysql, me parece raro que el problema sea la consulta

Comment: ocupo el mismo disenio para otras tablas con diferentes consultas y todo perfecto, por eso digo que el detalle es la consulta,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema esta en la consulta: estas usando una función de agregación (**count**) deberías intentar colocar un **group by** al resto de campos dentro de la consulta.

```
   group by empleados.noEmpleado, empleados.nombre, fechaHoraS
```

Comment: Toda la razon, muchas gracias!